# remove tags appearing at the end of a string

Tags: java

How can we remove tags appearing at the end of the string?

```
Input
    String test ="test string<.div class="og></div..>" 

outPut 
  String test ="test string";
```

while printing I only want `test string`. Some times at the the string test contains tags other than div tag. How to resolve this?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to remove all tags? Please post example input and output.

Comment: Why are they in the string to start with? Are you trying to parse HTML?

Comment: ya,parsed contents from the xml are in the string test

Comment: How are you parsing it? If you are parsing correctly you shouldn't get extra data in your string after the fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to process this:

```
    String test ="test string<div class=og></div>";
    String regExp = "<div \\S*</div>";
    String[] result = test.split(regExp);
    System.out.println(result[0]);
```

Comment: Some times at the the string test contains tags other than div tag

Answer (score 0):

String result = test.split("<")[0];